# android studio map activity and gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-mapview

I'm trying to use map activity in Android Studio which should work straight away.
i have error message on sync.

[image: Error alert]

If I click the UPDATE button it changes the version in the gradle build file but then an other error.

[image: 5.6.4 error]

version 5.6.4 doesn't exist.

the highest version is 2.3.1

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.1/

This seems an unsolvable problem.

Comment: Why not "don't remind me"?

Comment: . @azizbekian  : Ah ha....That worked. Why the hell does google tell us to upgrade to a non existant version?

Comment: Every time I start a new project, Andoid studio puts "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.6.4'" in the gradle build file. This is an error. It should be 2.3.0. Has no body else this "bug" or do I have a unique version of Andoid studio 2.3.1.